# Extract the mailto value and remove html tag if any in the string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby, sanitize

I want to extract the mailto value from the given string and also want to remove the html tag at the same time.

ex -> `"<mailto:demomail@gmail.com|demomail@gmail.com> helo<p> bye </p>"`
output -> demomail@gmail.com helo bye

If I use this -> `gsub(/<[^>]*>/,'')`
output -> helo bye

If I use this -> `ActionView::Base.full_sanitizer.sanitize(html_string, :tags => %w(img br p), :attributes => %w(src style))`
output -> helo bye

Can you suggest me how can i get my expected output?
expected output -> **demomail@gmail.com helo bye**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probem is that the mailto value is inside HTML tags, so when you remove the HTML tags, you remove the mailto value as well. It is definitely possible to construct a complex regular expression that would handle it, but I think it's much easier to extract the mailto value separately from the rest of the string. I would do this with a capturing group that extracts the value between `"mailto:"` and `"|"`. Then you can get the rest of of the output value by processing the full string with the `gsub` method you already have.

```rb
s = "<mailto:demomail@gmail.com|demomail@gmail.com> helo<p> bye </p>"

# Find the "mailto" value
s.match(/mailto:([^|]*)/)
=> #<MatchData "mailto:demomail@gmail.com" 1:"demomail@gmail.com">

# Full result with the matched email and the rest of the string with HTML tags removed
s.match(/mailto:([^|]*)/)[1] + s.gsub(/<[^>]*>/, "")
=> "demomail@gmail.com helo bye "
```

If the string starts with something other than the `<mailto>` tag, you could replace the whole tag with just the matched email address and then get rid of the other tags after that:

```rb
s = "this is <mailto:demomail@gmail.com|demomail@gmail.com> helo<p> bye </p>"

# Replace mailto tag with the email, then process the rest
# '\1' is a backreference to the first match
s.gsub(/<mailto:([^|]*)[^>]*>/, '\1').gsub(/<[^>]*>/, "")
=> "this is demomail@gmail.com helo bye "

# Alternatively, you can just process the mailto tag differently in the gsub block
s.gsub(/<[^>]*>/) do |tag|
  tag.include?("mailto:") ? tag.match(/mailto:([^|]*)/)[1] : ""
end
=> "this is demomail@gmail.com helo bye "
```

Comment: thanks for your solution. I want to ask one thing if the input is somehting like this "this is <mailto:demomail@gmail.com|demomail@gmail.com> helo<p> bye </p>" then it will give the output like this "demomail@gmail.comthis is  helo bye" but the actual output should be like this "this is demomail@gmail.com helo bye" do you have any idea how we can handle this thing.

Comment: or can we do this like first convert from "<mailto:" to "" and then "| any text >" to "". then maybe this solutin will work for if we have different email as well. what do you think.

Comment: Added a couple options for that sort of situation. Not sure which is more performant, but if you don't need to process super long strings, use whatever seems clearest to you. Your idea of clearing the two sides of the mailto tag also works, but it's 1 extra `gsub` compared to using the capturing group with the `'\1'` backreference. The implementation could be something like this: `s.gsub(/<mailto:/, "").gsub(/\|[^>]*>/, "").gsub(/<[^>]*>/, "")`

Comment: Thanks a lot and for your time to write this solution. Your solution is working.